# How to save the updated value of an array back to the firestore database?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, cardview

```
for (QueryDocumentSnapshot snapshot : Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult())) {
                    String value1 = snapshot.getString("QuestionName");
                    q_tv1.setText("Question: "+value1);
                    ArrayList<String> description = (ArrayList<String>) snapshot.get("Description");
                    Log.d(Tag,"output for des: "+description);
                    List<String> noOfOptions = (List<String>) snapshot.get("Options");
                    Log.d(Tag,"output for option: "+noOfOptions);
                    ArrayList<String> finalCount=(ArrayList<String>) snapshot.get("CountValue");
                    int size=noOfOptions.size();
                    Log.d(Tag,"size: "+finalCount);
                    for(i=0;i<=size-1;i++)
                    {
                        String op=noOfOptions.get(i);
                        String n=finalCount.get(i);

                        CardView cardview=new CardView(PublicVote.this);
                        LayoutParams layoutparams = new LayoutParams(
                                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                        );
                        LayoutParams layoutparams2 = new LayoutParams(
                                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                        );
                        cardview.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);
                        cardview.setRadius(25);
                        layoutparams.setMargins(10,10,10,10);
                        layoutparams2.setMargins(10,100,100,100);
                        cardview.setPadding(25, 25, 25, 25);
                        cardview.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                        cardview.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.YELLOW));
                        cardview.setMaxCardElevation(30);
                        cardview.setMaxCardElevation(6);

                        TextView textview = new TextView(PublicVote.this);
                        textview.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);
                        textview.append("o " +noOfOptions.get(i));
                        textview.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 25);
                        textview.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        textview.setPadding(25,25,25,25);
                        textview.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                        textview.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);


                        TextView textview1 = new TextView(PublicVote.this);
                        textview1.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);
                        textview1.append("Description: "+description.get(i));
                        textview1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 25);
                        textview1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        textview1.setPadding(25,25,25,25);
                        textview1.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                        textview1.setLayoutParams(layoutparams2);

                        cardview.addView(textview);
                        cardview.addView(textview1);
                        l1.addView(cardview);
                        cardview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                //Toast.makeText(PublicVote.this, n, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                n1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(n));
                                n1 = n1 + 1;
                                Log.d(Tag,"i->>: "+n1);
                            }
                        });

                    }
                }
```

This is my code above here my n1 is the countValue which is updated everytime the user clicks the cardview it keeps on incrementing. Now I want to save this incremented value i.e. the countValue (n1 here)back to the database which is given below.
[image]

Now here the options 121 and 122 have count value 10 and 5 respectively which gets incremented by 1 when any one option is clicked, lets say 121 is clicked so new value is 11 and 5(remains the same). This 11 and 5 needs to be updated back to the database, need help with this!

Comment: What exactly would you want to count? What is the expected result?

Comment: Hey I've updated the question please check it out

Comment: Did you know that Firestore has a build in function to increment field values? You may want to check out the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Hum, I suggest to set the settings in the XML layout instead of the setting in the class, it's more easy to visualize. If I understood should be like this, unless is another variable.

If the variable n1 is counting the numbers

> Log.d(Tag,"n1->>: "+ n1);

Try todo this:

> Log.d(Tag,"n1->>: "+ (n1 + 1));

or setting the number outside the operation

> n1 = n1 + 1;

This way every time they click on is going to set the number +1, try to do what i said about the settings in the xml.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot it worked! I've updated the question now so I want to know how to put back the updated countValue again to the database of the particular question.

Comment: I'll take a look at some tutorial to see if i can come with something. I learned just java and I didn't use the Firestore yet.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the two atomic operations in Cloud Firestore:

Transactions or Batch Writes on your snapshot and the document.

1. Update data with transactions when button click event is called.
2. Use Batch Writes at some point of interval.

[Check this link for reference.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#java_4)

Answer (score 0):

You can add your write back to firestore action inside `onClick` method as below.

```
cardview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Toast.makeText(PublicVote.this, n, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        n1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(n));
        n1 = n1 + 1;
        Log.d(Tag,"i->>: "+n1);
        //update database
        //add your update code here.
    }
});
```

You can find more on [[Firebase] Cloud Firestore — Add, Set, Update, Delete, Get data](https://saveyourtime.medium.com/firebase-cloud-firestore-add-set-update-delete-get-data-6da566513b1b)