# How to get all the values from ArrayList<String> (I'm only getting the last value )?

Tags: android, arrays, android-studio, arraylist, google-cloud-firestore

I want to display my CountValue  from the database given below in a piechart. I saved the CountValue in an ArrayList **finalCount** and  I dont know why am I getting the last value only of the arrayList in the piechart and not all the value.

Here's my code

```
for (QueryDocumentSnapshot snapshot : Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult())) {
                    String value1 = snapshot.getString("QuestionName");
                    q_tv1.setText("Poll: " + value1);
                    ArrayList<String> CountValue = (ArrayList<String>) snapshot.get("CountValue");
                    Log.d(Tag, "output for des: " + CountValue);
                    List<String> noOfOptions = (List<String>) snapshot.get("Options");
                    Log.d(Tag, "output for option: " + noOfOptions);
                    ArrayList<String> finalCount=(ArrayList<String>) snapshot.get("CountValue");
                    int size = noOfOptions.size();
                    Log.d(Tag, "size: " + size);

                    for (int i = 0; i <= size-1; i++) {
                     

                        String op = noOfOptions.get(i);
                        String n = finalCount.get(i);

                        n1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(n));

                        Log.d(Tag, "i->>: " + n1);

                            ArrayList<PieEntry> visitors = new ArrayList<>();
                            visitors.add(new PieEntry(n1, op));

                        PieDataSet pieDataSet = new PieDataSet(visitors, "Answer");
                            pieDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
                            pieDataSet.setValueTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                            pieDataSet.setValueTextSize(16f);

                            PieData pieData = new PieData(pieDataSet);

                            pieChart.setData(pieData);
                            pieChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
                            pieChart.setCenterText("Answer");
                            pieChart.animate();

                    }
                }
```

**Here's my database**

[image]

In the code, I converted String n  to int n1 which has the finalCount values which is [10,15] but I'm only getting 15 in the piechart and the last option name

```
 ArrayList<PieEntry> visitors = new ArrayList<>();
 visitors.add(new PieEntry(n1, op));
```

**My output screenshot looks like this, as you can see only 15 is displayed and not 10 and 15 both**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ArrayList<PieEntry> visitors = new ArrayList<>();
visitors.add(new PieEntry(n1, op));
```

Add `ArrayList<PieEntry> visitors = new ArrayList<>();` top of the for loop.

```
ArrayList<PieEntry> visitors = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i <= size-1; i++) {
   //code goes here
   visitors.add(new PieEntry(n1, op));
   //code goes here
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66719503/how-to-save-the-updated-value-of-an-array-back-to-the-firestore-database/66731578#66731578 - if you could help me w this question as well, it'd be a great help